# Magento 2: Custom input field values not saved in product form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, product-attribute, ui

I have to add a more complex input to the product form. For this, I have added the following UI configuration

```
<fieldset name="fieldset_name">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">A Label</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="fielset_name_container">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Block\BlockClass</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>
</fieldset>
```

The block class itself loads a .phtml template containing an input field with the name attribute `product[<attributeCode>]`. When I now enter a value and push the save button, the new value I entered in the input does not get saved.

What do I have to do to get it to save?

Comment: You can use Product modifier. 
Ref
1)http://www.sunshinebiz.cn/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_modifier_concept.html 2)http://www.sunshinebiz.cn/guides/v2.2/howdoi/customize_product.html